# Arithmetic progression & Geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

If the $m$-th, $n$-th, and $p$-th terms of an A.p. and G.p. are equal and are $x,y,z$ respectively, prove that $x^{y-z}$. $y^{z-x}$. $z^{x-y}= 1$. To solve this question what I did is simply kept values of $x,y,z$ from G.P. (i.e. for $x = ar^{m-1}$ so on).
Can you help me to solve this in an more interesting way.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d$ be the common difference of the A.P. and $r$ be the common ratio of the G.P. Then

$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{y}{x}=r^{n-m}=r^{(y-x)/d}\\
\displaystyle\frac{x}{z}=r^{m-p}=r^{(x-z)/d}\\
\displaystyle\frac{z}{y}=r^{p-n}=r^{(z-y)/d}\end{cases}$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^z\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)^y\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)^x&=r^{[z(y-x)+y(x-z)+x(z-y)]/d}\\
x^{y-z}y^{z-x}z^{x-y}&=1
\end{align}

Comment: Nice answer (+1). But do these numbers exist?

Comment: I have one. Take $d=-3$,  $r=-2$, $x=1$, $y=-2$ and $z=-8$. $x$, $y$, $z$ are the 1st, the 2nd and the 4th terms.

Comment: Tried with $n=3, p=6, d=2$, which gives $y=5, z=11$ for the AP but $y=1.6915, z=3.7214$ for the GP.

Comment: OK, that's a good example. Is that the only case?

Comment: Another example: $d=\frac{-9}{8}$, $r=\frac{-1}{2}$, $x=3$, $y=\frac{3}{4}$ and $z=\frac{-3}{8}$. $x$ , $y$, $z$ are the 1st, the 3rd and the 4th terms.

Comment: @hypergeometric I just  take arbitrary $x$, $m$, $n$, $p$ and use WolframAlpha to solve. It seems that there are (infinitely?) many possible cases.

Comment: OK. It appears that this is possible only for negative $r$.

Comment: It seems to be. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a+(m-1)d=br^{m-1}$ etc. where $a,d$ are the first term & the common difference respectively of the AP and $b,r$ are the first term & the common ratio respectively of the GP

$y-z=(n-p)d$

$$\prod_{\text{cyc}}x^{y-z}=\prod_{\text{cyc}}(br^{m-1})^{d(n-p)}=\left(\dfrac br\right)^{d\sum_{\text{cyc}}(n-p)}r^{d\sum_{\text{cyc}}m(n-p)}$$

Now $\sum_{\text{cyc}}(n-p)=0=\sum_{\text{cyc}}m(n-p)$

Answer (score 0):

Using the formulas: $a_n-a_m=d(n-m)$ (A.P.) and $b_n=b_m\cdot r^{n-m}$ (G.P.),

$$x^{y-z}y^{z-x}z^{x-y}=x^{d(n-p)}\cdot (xr^{n-m})^{d(p-m)}\cdot (xr^{p-m})^{d(m-n)}=x^0\cdot r^0=1.$$